# Why image decoded by ffmpeg has a border?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

After decoding some videos from iphone, I find the image has a strange border on the right.

It is not black but some random pix (width:4).
why i get the border?
how to cut this border or to turn it to black?

Most of videos dont have this problem.

[image]

here is the sample code:
the code will load a video from memory, and decode it

```cpp
int VideoParseFFmpeg::read_packet(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size) {
  struct buffer_data *bd = (struct buffer_data *) opaque;
  buf_size = FFMIN(buf_size, bd->size_);

  if (!buf_size)
    return AVERROR_EOF;

  memcpy(buf, bd->ptr_, buf_size);
  bd->ptr_ += buf_size;
  bd->size_ -= buf_size;

  return buf_size;
}

int VideoParseFFmpeg::LoadContent(const std::string &video_content) {
  int ret = 0;
  ...

  video_size_ = video_content.size();
  avio_ctx_buffer_size_ = video_size_ + AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE;
  avio_ctx_buffer_ = static_cast<uint8_t *>(av_malloc(avio_ctx_buffer_size_));
  bd_.ptr_ = (uint8_t *)(video_content.c_str());
  bd_.size_ = video_content.size();

  av_register_all();
  input_ctx_ = avformat_alloc_context();
  avio_ctx_ = avio_alloc_context(avio_ctx_buffer_,
                                 avio_ctx_buffer_size_,
                                 0,
                                 &bd_,
                                 &read_packet,
                                 NULL,
                                 NULL);

  if ((ret = av_probe_input_buffer(avio_ctx_, &in_fmt_, "", NULL, 0, 0)) < 0) {
    LOGGER_WARN(Log::GetLog(), "fail to prob input, err [{}]", AVERROR(ret));
    return -1;
  }
  input_ctx_->pb = avio_ctx_;

  /* open the input file */
  if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&input_ctx_, "", in_fmt_, NULL)) != 0) {
    LOGGER_WARN(Log::GetLog(), "fail to open input, err [{}]", AVERROR(ret));
    return -1;
  }

  if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(input_ctx_, NULL)) < 0) {
    LOGGER_WARN(Log::GetLog(),
                "fail to find input stream information, err[{}]",
                AVERROR(ret));
    return -1;
  }

  /* find the video stream information */
  if ((ret = av_find_best_stream(input_ctx_, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, &decoder_, 0)) < 0) {
    LOGGER_WARN(Log::GetLog(), "fail to find a video stream from input, err[{}]", ret);
    return -1;
  }
  video_stream_idx_ = ret;

  if (!(decoder_ctx_ = avcodec_alloc_context3(decoder_))) {
    LOGGER_WARN(Log::GetLog(), "fail to alloc avcodec context");
    return -1;
  }
  video_stream_ = input_ctx_->streams[video_stream_idx_];
  if ((ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(decoder_ctx_, video_stream_->codecpar)) < 0) {
    LOGGER_WARN(Log::GetLog(), "fail to convert parameters to context, err [{}]", ret);
    return -1;
  }

  if ((ret = avcodec_open2(decoder_ctx_, decoder_, NULL)) < 0) {
        LOGGER_WARN(Log::GetLog(), "fail to open decodec, err[{}]", ret);
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}

void VideoParseFFmpeg::GetFrames(std::vector<cv::Mat> &frames) {
  while (1) {
      ...
      decode_write(decoder_ctx_, &packet_, &buffer, frames);
      ...
  }
//flush
...
}

cv::Mat VideoParseFFmpeg::avFrame2Mat(AVFrame *pAvFrame,
                                      AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx,
                                      AVPixelFormat src_fmt) {
  AVFrame *pFrameBGR = av_frame_alloc();   //  存储解码后转换的BGR数据
  int w = pAvFrame->width;
  int h = pAvFrame->height;
  auto size = av_image_get_buffer_size(AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, w, h, 1);
  cv::Mat out(h, w, CV_8UC3);

  int ret = av_image_fill_arrays(pFrameBGR->data,
                                 pFrameBGR->linesize,
                                 out.data,
                                 AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                                 w,
                                 h,
                                 1);

  img_convert_ctx_ = sws_getCachedContext(img_convert_ctx_,
                                          w,
                                          h,
                                          ConvertDeprecatedFormat(src_fmt),
                                          w,
                                          h,
                                          AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                                          SWS_BICUBIC,
                                          NULL, NULL, NULL);

  sws_scale(img_convert_ctx_,
            (const uint8_t *const *) pAvFrame->data,
            pAvFrame->linesize,
            0,
            pCodecCtx->height,
            pFrameBGR->data,
            pFrameBGR->linesize);

  av_free(pFrameBGR);
  return out;
}

int VideoParseFFmpeg::decode_write(AVCodecContext *avctx,
                                   AVPacket *packet,
                                   uint8_t **buffer,
                                   std::vector<cv::Mat> &p_mat_out) {
  AVFrame *frame = NULL, *sw_frame = NULL;
  AVFrame *tmp_frame = NULL;
  int ret = 0;

  ret = avcodec_send_packet(avctx, packet);
  ...
  while (1) {
    auto clear = [&frame, &sw_frame, this] {
      if (frame != NULL)
        av_frame_free(&frame);
      if (sw_frame != NULL)
        av_frame_free(&sw_frame);
      av_packet_unref(&packet_);
    };
    ...

    ret = avcodec_receive_frame(avctx, frame);
    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
      clear();
      return 0;
    } else if (ret < 0) {
      LOGGER_WARN(Log::GetLog(), "error while decoding, err[{}]", AVERROR(ret));
      clear();
      return ret;
    }

    tmp_frame = frame;
    p_mat_out.push_back(avFrame2Mat(tmp_frame,
                                    avctx,
                                    (AVPixelFormat) tmp_frame->format));
    clear();
  }
}
```

After replacing lib tcmalloc with a newer version, the border turns to be a black line (used to be a random line), like this.

[image: black line]

there is image content in the area of the border in the original image, how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like the encoder doesn't set cropping flags correctly.

Comment: A lot of codecs have to encode images with dimensions as a multiple of 16, so for example HD is actually 1920*1088. without knowing what your video source is or how you're decoding it it is difficult to help further, please provide a [mre]

Comment: I have pasted my code block. 
As mentioned above, after changing the tcmalloc to a new version, the border turns to be black. Orz....
In the original video, there is image content in the area of the border. how can i remove  the black area, and show the real content of image?